# How can I Update multi record at a time from MSFlexGrid1 to data1 in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

I create a project add some item (C_Number,E Number, Model, Type, Color, Key No, Price(numeric field)) in MSFlexGrid1. then add a button when click on this add the record in data1, but only 1(one) data add in the data1 database.
I use access database. How can I add all (minimum 2 or maximum 12 record) add in data1 database. Please help me.......

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()
Dim count As Integer
Data2.Recordset.AddNew
MSFlexGrid1.Col = 0
Data2.Recordset.Fields("C_Number") = MSFlexGrid1.Text
MSFlexGrid1.Col = 1
Data2.Recordset.Fields("E_Number") = MSFlexGrid1.Text
Data2.Recordset.Update
Data2.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: VB6 is not VB.Net, do not abuse the Tags line

Comment: please help me please

Comment: Sorry but I never used MSFlexGrid